# Como comparar a estrutura de dois bancos de dados SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso fazer a comparação da estrutura `DDL` de dois bancos de dados, onde um é o banco de produção e o outro é o de homologação de um sistema.

Quais ferramentas podem ser usadas para fazer isso?

Comment: https://dbcompare.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 4):

Você mesmo pode fazer uma ferramenta para isso; é muito simples (e é ainda mais simples porque você tem só um tipo de servidor de banco de dados envolvido).

Basta consultar os metadados do banco a fim de listar as tabelas e as colunas, por exemplo:

```
select TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_CATALOG = 'nome_base'

select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'nome_tabela'
```

Há views e tabelas de sistema para consultar qualquer info sobre os bancos no servidor (*stored procedures*, *triggers*, *constraints*, *index*...), dá uma olhada na documentação.

Depois você pode comparar as listas apresentando as diferenças encontradas conforme sua necessidade.

Answer (score 3):

Você gostaria de retornar a estrutura das tabelas mesmo ou os dados que existem entre as tabelas de um banco ou outro ?

Se precisa dos dados existe a opção de montar um INNER JOIN:

```
select TB1.coluna_tb1, TB2.coluna_tb2 from [nome_banco1].[dbo].tabela_banco1 TB1
inner join [nome_banco2].[dbo].tabela_banco2 TB2 on TB1.PK = TB2.PK
where TB1.coluna_tb1 = 'VALOR' and TB2.coluna_tb2 = 'VALOR'
```

Caso seja da estrutura, acredito que a resposta acima já tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Segue o meu exemplo:

```sql
SELECT  COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE FROM(
    select *
    from DatabaseA.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
    UNION ALL 
    select *
    from  PortoSeguro.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where DataBaseB= 'table_name'
) AS TMP
GROUP BY  COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Não satisfeito com as respostas anteriores. Coloco aqui meu exemplo comparando primeiro as tabelas existentes e dois os campos das tabelas.

```
SELECT A.NAME, B.NAME  
FROM BANCO1.SYS.tables A
LEFT JOIN BANCO2.SYS.TABLES B ON A.NAME = B.NAME 
GROUP BY A.NAME, B.NAME 
HAVING A.NAME IS NULL 
OR B.NAME IS NULL 

SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT T.NAME TABELA, C.NAME COLUNA, C.system_type_id, C.max_length, C.precision   
FROM BANCO1.SYS.all_columns C
INNER JOIN BANCO1.SYS.tables T ON T.object_id = C.object_id ) A 

LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT T.NAME TABELA, C.NAME COLUNA, C.system_type_id, C.max_length, C.precision   
FROM BANCO2.SYS.all_columns C
INNER JOIN BANCO2.SYS.tables T ON T.object_id = C.object_id ) B ON B.TABELA = A.TABELA AND B.COLUNA=A.COLUNA 
WHERE A.system_type_id != B.system_type_id 
OR A.max_length != B.max_length
OR A.precision != B.precision
```